# Visual Studio 2015 string literal not always constant?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ConstStr
{
    char const* const Str;
    constexpr struct ConstStr(char const* str) :Str(str) {}
};

struct Container {
    static constexpr struct ConstStr hey{ "hey" };
};


struct StructScope1
{
    struct ConstStr {
        char const* const Str;
        constexpr ConstStr(char const* str) :Str(str) {}
    };
    struct Container {
        static constexpr StructScope1::ConstStr hey{ "hey" };
    };
};

struct StructScope2
{
    struct Container {
        static constexpr ConstStr hey{ "hey" };
    };
};

struct Container2 {
    static constexpr struct StructScope1::ConstStr hey { "hey" };
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    cout << "Container::hey.Str " << Container::hey.Str << endl;
    cout << "StructScope1::Container::hey.Str " << StructScope1::Container::hey.Str << endl;
    cout << "StructScope2::Container::hey.Str " << StructScope2::Container::hey.Str << endl;
    cout << "Container2::hey.Str " << Container2::hey.Str << endl;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.  For some reason, the declaration/initialization of `StructScope1::Container::hey` fails to compile.  It gives the error

> expression must have a constant value

But I initialize the same code in other places, and it works just fine.  Is this a compiler bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: "_in other places_" Like what or where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's misleading compile error message.

This works:

```
struct StructScope1
{
    struct ConstStr {
        char const* const Str;
        constexpr ConstStr(char const* str) :Str(str) {}
    };
    struct Container;
};

struct StructScope1::Container{
    static constexpr StructScope1::ConstStr hey{ "hey" };
};
```

Unless I define the nested class outside, the `hey` tries to be defined before the constructor (the constructor must see the already constructed `hey` by standard rules).

Clang is bit more clear:

```
a.cpp:23:49: error: constexpr variable 'hey' must be initialized by a constant expression
    static constexpr StructScope1::ConstStr hey{ "hey" };
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp:23:49: note: undefined constructor 'ConstStr' cannot be used in a constant expression
a.cpp:20:19: note: declared here constexpr ConstStr(char const* str) :Str(str) {}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying.  When StructScope1::Container is defined inside StructScope1, and StructScope1::ConstStr is defined inside StructScope1, then StructScope1::Container::hey is defined before StructScope1::ConstStr::ConstStr (the constructor).  So hey is trying to use that destructor before it is defined.  Is that correct?

Comment: I mean constructor, not destructor.  Apparently, I can't edit my comment to fix that.

Comment: @user You can delete and write a new comment though. ;; Yes, that would be my observation. I will leave explanation why that happens to some spec guru. My interpretation is that static members are defined before constructors, for the purpose the constructor may need to use them (ergo the `hey` see only a declaration when it's defined) ;; Though it crashes on my VS2015 so probably not safe (works fine w/ clang)